# How to Store az keyvault secret list -o table output in array? Azure CLI , Shell Script

Tags: azure, shell, command-line-interface, azure-keyvault

`az keyvault secret list --vault-name $VaultName --query "[?attributes.expires<='2022-06-30']" -o table`

Output:

```
ContentType |  Name    
------------- ----------    
Content1       KV-Secret1    
Content2       KV-Secret2
```

The  main purpose to store output into array is, I want to get two values into different variables i.e,**Required Values $varibale1 = Content1 , $variable2 = KV-Secret1**

I need to list all the secrets from specific keyvault that is going to expire in 30 days from current date, then I need two values of that secrets - 1.secret name and 2.secrettype, that values will be use into another script to reset the secrets expiry date.

Comment: which language are you looking for? powershell?

Comment: @silent CLI Shell. I am creating .sh script

Answer (score 1):

**Thank You [sikumars-msft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/767136/key-vaults-secretskey-expiration.html) for your suggestion, Posting your suggestion as community wiki so other who encounter the same requirement so it will be benficial for them**

You must specify each keys vault names in URI (let say: `"GET", "/" + https://keyvaults["Vault_Uri"] + "keys?api-version=7.0"` or `"GET", "/" + https://keyvaults["Vault_Uri"] + "secrets?api-version=7.0"` ) to retrieve expiry dates of respective keys and secrets because these information are part of the data plane which allows you to work with the data stored in a key vault. Hence, you can't use management plane endpoint `"GET", '/subscriptions/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults?api-version=2019-09-01`' to retrieve information about data stored in Azure KeyVault.

To learn more about different type of key vault plane, refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/25726/what-is-management-and-data-plane-in-azure-key-vau.html

Therefore, you need to get all key vault name created in your subscription and load them into some variable then you can retrieve expiry date of keys and secrets accordingly. In case if you can't retrieve Key Vault name from variable then you could think so using alternative approach of enabling Azure Key vault logging to monitor Microsoft.KeyVault.SecretNearExpiry to get notification using Azure automation (Event grid) or Logic App as explained below:

Azure Key Vault logging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/logging?tabs=Vault
Creating a Logic App to remind Key Vault key Expiry: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/398632/creating-a-logic-app-to-remind-key-